# Windows 8 store runtime error

Tags: windows-store-apps, installation

I just installed windows 8 from the microsoft action pack (we have subscription for that).
After installing it, everything works as espected, but when I want to open the store I get an error message.

(I didn't install any software yet, so I don't understand why I get this error, my laptop is running in a domain)

```
runtime error 
wwahost.exe
r6034

an application has made an attempt to load the C library incorrectly
please contact the application's support team for more information.
```